# Styles with "inject: false" in angular.json do not get the hashing

Tags: angular

I'm trying to add multiple themes to my Angular 12 app, and I set my `angular.json` as follows:

```json
"styles": [
  {
    "input": "src/styles.scss",
    "inject": false,
    "bundleName": "assets/themes/default"
  },
  {
    "input": "src/styles-high-contrast.scss",
    "inject": false,
    "bundleName": "assets/themes/high-contrast"
  }
]
```

When I build the app for production, however, these files do not get a hash in their filenames:

```sh
$ find dist -name '*.css'
dist/assets/themes/high-contrast.css
dist/assets/themes/default.css
```

With the default settings:

```json
"styles": [
  "src/styles.scss"
]
```

instead, I get this:

```sh
$ find dist -name '*.css'
dist/styles.1ee1562d01e33dd2000e.css
```

This means that the files won't be cache-busted, which is obviously a no-go.

However, the files are included fine and the stylesheet is applied properly.

Can anyone offer any insight as to why the filenames are not hashed?

Thanks!

Comment: If it hashed how would you reference those style in html?

Comment: Yeah, I just figured it out too :) I saw this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12552 but I can't find a satisfactory resolution. Got any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

remove   bundleName .It's create random name.